# How to evaluating expression in robot framework with run keyword if

Tags: robotframework

I want to invoke different method base on the expression result, but only get error on Mac

I am using robotframework-ride as IDE:
the expression on win10(python 2.7.14+roboframework3.1.1+robotframework-ride1.7.3.1) work normally, but on Mac(python3.7.3+robotframework3.1.2+robotframework-ride1.7.3.1)

```
Run Keyword If | '${PLATFORM}'=='android' |  Android Open App | ELSE IF |‘${PLATFORM}’==‘ios’ | IOS Open App
```

NOTE:${PLATFORM} is a global variable, it's value can be android or iOS

I expect to invoke Android Open App or IOS Open App base on the expression result, but get error:

```
FAIL : Evaluating expression '‘ios’==‘ios’' failed: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier (<string>, line 1)
```

Comment: will the below condition works in your mac? Just try invoke a single condition first.

`Run Keyword If | '${PLATFORM}'=='android'` 

Next, maybe try not to use ELSE IF, have a condition for 'ios' in a separate line/row. Not sure if this keyword has issue with python3 or Mac.

Answer (score 3):

This symbol ‘ is wrong in below condition

```
 |‘${PLATFORM}’==‘ios’ |
```

It should be given as below

```
|'${PLATFORM}'=='ios'| 


 Run Keyword If | '${PLATFORM}'=='android' | Android Open App | ELSE IF |'${PLATFORM}'=='ios' | IOS Open App
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone! I found the reason, the symbol' is automatically transfer to ‘, and I don't know why, when I copy '${PLATFORM}'=='android' and put it behind else if, then change text to '${PLATFORM}'=='ios', the symbol' automatically transfer to ' too! it is so strange! I have to change the robotframework resource file to txt format and open with Mac text editor, modify the symbol '